# visual studio code keeps display an error after updating flutter to v 2.10.3

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

> ```
> after upgrading my old flutter with latest version of flutter 2.10.3 vs code keeps display the errors down below :
>
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8:
> ```
>
> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
> ^
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' as ui;
> ^
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner_theme.dart:5:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:5:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
> ^
> /C:/flutter2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet_theme.dart:5:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
> import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
>
> [Done] exited with code=254 in 102.936 seconds
>
> here is result of flutter doctor command
>
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√]
> Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.19042.1526], locale en-US) [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0) [√] Chrome - develop for
> the web [!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build
> Tools 2019 16.11.10)
> X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete. Please reinstall Visual Studio. [√] Android Studio (version 2021.1) [√]
> IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2) [√] VS Code (version
> 1.65.2) [√] Connected device (4 available) [√] HTTP Host Availability
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
>
> NOTE : even Android studio displays such error , both of Android
> studio and VS code don't connect to the emulator properly (Pixel XL
> API 30)

Comment: post your full code

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error when I try to run it from the run button at the top  right corner
[image: 1]

But I notice there are three options above the main method there are three options I selected Debug and it successfully worked!

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem in vs code.
instead of clicking "run the project" in vs code i clicked "start debugging" and it woreked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).